# How to load a local image to WebGL context

Tags: css, image, image-processing, azure-maps

I was trying Azure maps Symbol feature. I wanted to add a custom image as symbol.

When i used path of local image, it was not working.

**"All resources, such as icon images, must be loaded into the WebGL context."**

Please help me how to make local image to be loaded as webGL context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must add your image to the maps image sprite before you the symbol layer can use it. You would pass the URL and a unique name for the image into the map.imageSprite.add function. This is a Promise that you have to wait for as the image is loaded asynchronously. Once loaded, you can then set the `image` option of the symbol layers `iconOptions` to the unique name of the image.

Some additional code samples can be found here: https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=custom-symbol-image-icon

**Update:**

Here is a code block show how to add an image to the maps image sprite (WebGL context).

```
//Wait until the map resources are ready.
map.events.add('ready', function () {
    //Create a data source and add it to the map.
    datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
    map.sources.add(datasource);

    //Load the custom image icon into the map resources.
    map.imageSprite.add('my-custom-icon', '/images/icons/showers.png').then(function () {
    
        //Add a layer for rendering point data as symbols.
        map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
            iconOptions: {
                //Pass in the id of the custom icon that was loaded into the map resources.
                image: 'my-custom-icon'
            }
        }));
    }); 
});
```

If you have multiple images you want to use, you can create an array of the imade add promises, then use `Promise.all`. Here is a good code sample: https://samples.azuremaps.com/?sample=data-driven-symbol-icons And here is a simply code block example:

```
//Wait until the map resources are ready.
map.events.add('ready', function () {

    //Create a data source and add it to the map.
    datasource = new atlas.source.DataSource();
    map.sources.add(datasource);

    //Create an array of custom icon promises to load into the map. 
    var iconPromises = [
        map.imageSprite.add('gas_station_icon', '/images/icons/gas_station_pin.png'),
        map.imageSprite.add('grocery_store_icon', '/images/icons/grocery_cart_pin.png'),
        map.imageSprite.add('restaurant_icon', '/images/icons/restaurant_pin.png'),
        map.imageSprite.add('school_icon', '/images/icons/school_pin.png'),
    ];

    //Load all the custom image icons into the map resources.
    Promise.all(iconPromises).then(function () {

        //Add a layer for rendering point data as symbols.
        map.layers.add(new atlas.layer.SymbolLayer(datasource, null, {
            iconOptions: {
                //Use a data driven expression based on properties in the features to determine which image to use for each feature.
                image: [
                    'match',

                    //In this example each feature has a "EntityType" property that we use to select the appropriate icon.
                    ['get', 'EntityType'],  

                    //For each entity type, specify the icon name to use.
                    'Gas Station', 'gas_station_icon',
                    'Grocery Store', 'grocery_store_icon',
                    'Restaurant', 'restaurant_icon',
                    'School', 'school_icon',

                    //Default fallback icon.
                    'marker-blue'
                ]
            }
        }));
    });
```

Comment: This did not answer the question: "How to load a local image to WebGL context?". Your information is correct, but does not help if you have a local image which is not loaded to WebGL.

Comment: Actually, it does, thus why the asker of the question marked this response as the answer. But I've added an update with a code block for you. Note that files on the local filesystem can't be added and have to hosted (browser limitation of the fetch API for security purposes).

Comment: Nice update! So do I understand correctly that all your images are all in the ````images```` folder? No need to upload it somewhere else?

Comment: They are hosted with the web app in an images folder. You can't access images that are in a local folder on your computer from a browser. The fetch API in the browser purposely prevents this for security reasons.

Comment: Ah I see...I guess this is why it threw an error when I tried to implement this locally. So to make it work locally, can I upload my SVGs into my Azure repo and then link to the files which are then online? Or are there more steps to it?

Comment: You can upload your images to Azure, or you could host them locally using localhost. If using visual studio code, the Live server plugin is an easy way to do this: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide us your code?

I've tried to add local file as image to Azure Maps symbol layer. See examples here: [click](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-maps/map-add-pin#add-a-custom-icon-to-a-symbol-layer).

Local file `file:///D:/showers.png` failed with error: `URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.`, but same file on `localhost` server worked well:
[image]

P.S. Maybe I do not clearly understand the problem?